# Water spilling out of motor

Tags: engine, chevrolet

So I have a truck that has been parked for a year and when I try to jump start it, it turns on but as soon as I put the truck on drive it shuts off so I bought a new alternator and put it in and still keeps doing it can y’all let me know how to fix that, another thing is that when I pour water for the motor it goes straight through and out the back of the motor through a whole, is there suppose to be a plug or cap that belongs there and if so can y’all tell me what it’s called.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The coolant you're adding is likely exiting through a broken hose. If the truck was parked for a year, in a hot or sunny environment, it's very possible for hoses to disintegrate. Also, a bad alternator will not cause the truck to shut off when you put it in drive. Any error codes (Check Engine Light), other unexpected behavior, etc.?

Comment: That or it froze in winter due to no anti freeze.

Answer (score 1):

There are Core plugs or freeze plugs in the block, one of these has probably come out or been damaged which will let water pour out. Sometime if the water freezes because of lack of antifreeze it will push the core plugs out. This could also crack the engine block

Comment: frostplugs can be replaced and if you are in luck the engine block has survived.